# preventing race conditions by using strict alteration

Tags: c, locking, while-loop, race-condition, critical-section

I found the following code in a book about operating systems. It is a technique called "strict alteration" that is supposed to prevent race conditions between processes by using a lock when a process enters a critical region. I understand race conditions, but I don't quite understand this code.

```
// process 0
while(TRUE) {
   while(turn != 0)   /* loop */
   critical_region();
   turn = 1;
   noncritical_region();
}
```

There is also this code that is right next to it.

```
// process 1
while(TRUE) {
   while(turn != 1)   /* loop */
   critical_region();
   turn = 0;
   noncritical_region();
}
```

I think there might by a typo in this code for the second while loop. If there isn't, then can someone explain how this code works? The explanation in the book didn't make sense to me. It only makes sense on a very general, abstract level. However when I look at this code I just don't get it.

Comment: Found [this page](http://www.if.uidaho.edu/~bgray/classes/cs341/doc/petersons.html) while googling for strict alteration. Looks a whole lot like your example.

Comment: Looks like it will protect critical_region() fine as long as turn is set to 0 or 1.

Comment: Ok, but the text also described a situation where one process finishes early and somehow this causes it to block the other process even though it is not in the critical region. That doesn't make sense from looking at the code.

Comment: @Ze Blob - The code on that page has an important semicolon that this code doesn't.

Comment: @z-buffer - Does the code in the book really say `while(turn != 1)` or does it actually say `while(turn != 1);` like the site @Ze Blob linked to?

Comment: The code in the book doesn't have any whitespace. I just changed it to make it easier to read. There is no ; at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the *turn* variable contains the number of the process that's allowed to enter the critical section.  Hopefully it does some useful work here, then it explicitly allows the *other* process to enter the critical section by changing the turn variable.  As a result, the processes each take a turn doing work, repeatedly.

This comes to a screeching halt when one of the process terminates.  It will be given the turn by the live process but never gives the turn back because it doesn't run anymore.  The live process won't be doing any useful work.